# Remove only Horizontal Border from Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, border

I only want the horizontal line to be removed.

Meaning rows should not have lines and column should have lines.

In my code, there is no line in row as well as column.

I tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style>
    #chiru_inv>tbody tr:first-of-type td {
      border-color: #f9f9f9;
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    #chiru_inv tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
      border-top: none;
    }
    
    #chiru_inv>tbody tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
      border-color: #f9f9f9;
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    #chiru_inv tr:nth-of-type(3) td {
      border-top: none;
    }
    
    #chiru_inv>tbody tr:nth-of-type(3) td {
      border-color: #f9f9f9;
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    #chiru_inv tr:nth-of-type(4) td {
      border-top: none;
    }
    
    @media print {
      table {
        border: 0 !important;
      }
      #chiru_inv tr:first-of-type td {
        border: 0 !important;
      }
      #chiru_inv tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
        border: 0 !important;
      }
      #chiru_inv tr:nth-of-type(3) td {
        border: 0 !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <center>
    <table id="chiru_inv" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">
          <h1>Company<br /><span style="font-size: 75%;">Number</span></h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3><span style="float: left;">Demo&nbsp;(2)</span></h3>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3><span style="float: right;">2017-11-16 12:18:15</span></h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Sr.</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="border:none !important">
          1 </td>
        <td style="border:none !important">
          Shirt &nbsp;(DC Dry Clean)
        </td>
        <td style="border:none !important">
          2 </td>
        <td style="border:none !important">
          100 </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td style="border:none !important">
          2 </td>
        <td style="border:none !important">
          Saree &nbsp;(RP ROll Polish)
        </td>
        <td style="border:none !important">
          2 </td>
        <td style="border:none !important">
          100 </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Two Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
        <td><strong>200</strong></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

I only want the horizontal line to be removed after the first row, i.e after Sr, Item and all, and before amount row (the last row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the inline stye (border:none!important;) and add

border-top:none;
border-bottom:none;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 .table-bordered>tbody>tr>th {
    border: 0px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style>



 #chiru_inv>tbody tr:first-of-type td,
 #chiru_inv>tbody tr:nth-of-type(2) td{
    border: none;
 }

    #chiru_inv>tbody tr td:first-of-type{
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

 #chiru_inv>tbody tr td:last-of-type{
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
 }

 #chiru_inv>tbody tr td{
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
 }


    @media print {
      table {
        border: 0 !important;
      }


   #chiru_inv tr td:first-of-type{
       border-left: 1px solid #ddd !important;
       }

    #chiru_inv tr td:last-of-type{
       border-right: 1px solid #ddd !important;
    }

  #chiru_inv tr:first-of-type td {
          border: 0 !important;
        }
        #chiru_inv tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
          border: 0 !important;
        }
        #chiru_inv tr:nth-of-type(3) td {
          border: 0 !important;
        }

   #chiru_inv>tbody tr td{
     border-left: none!important;
    border-right: none!important;
    }
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <center>
    <table id="chiru_inv" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">
          <h1>Company<br /><span style="font-size: 75%;">Number</span></h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3><span style="float: left;">Demo&nbsp;(2)</span></h3>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3><span style="float: right;">2017-11-16 12:18:15</span></h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Sr.</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          1 </td>
        <td>
          Shirt &nbsp;(DC Dry Clean)
        </td>
        <td>
          2 </td>
        <td>
          100 </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>
          2 </td>
        <td>
          Saree &nbsp;(RP ROll Polish)
        </td>
        <td>
          2 </td>
        <td>
          100 </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Two Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
        <td><strong>200</strong></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```